# Proof on linear operator in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is orthogonal if and only if it maps open balls to open balls of the same radius

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I encountered the following lemma when reading through *Real Analysis, Royden, 5th ed (pp. 186)*. The statement is as follows

> A linear operator $L: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is orthogonal if and only if it maps open balls onto open balls of the same radius.

In the book, *orthogonal* is defined as $\langle L(x), L(y) \rangle = \langle x, y \rangle$ for all $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

**Two** confusions arose as I tried understanding its proof.

**Problem 1**:
The author claimed that

> Let $B$ be the open ball centered at the origin that has radius $1$ (i.e. $B = B_1(0)$). Then a linear operator maps open balls onto open balls of the same radius if and only if it maps $B$ onto $B$.

I can see why the *implied by* direction holds: Suppose $L(B) = B$, then for $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $r > 0$, write
$$
  B_r(x_0) = rB + x_0
$$
so that
$$
  L(B_r(x_0)) = rL(B) + L(x_0) = rB + L(x_0) = B_r(L(x_0)).
$$

However, I cannot prove that $L$ maps open balls onto open balls of the same radius implies $L(B) = B$. The problem here is that it is not clear if $L$ preserves the center of the ball. If $L(B) = B(y_0)$, then using the above formula,
$$
  L(B_r(0)) = rL(B) + L(0) = r(B + y_0) + 0 = B_r + ry_0.
$$
We know that $0 \in B_r$ for all $r > 0$, so $L(0) = 0 \in  B_r + ry_0$, i.e.
$$
  || ry_0 || < r \quad \implies \quad || y_0 || < 1.
$$
This is as far as I can figure out. Clearly this can be remedied by further assuming that $L$ preserves the center of the ball, but I would like to know if the original claim is indeed true.

**Problem 2**: Later in the prove, the author writes

> To prove the converse, assume $L$ maps $B$ onto $B$. So $L$ is invertible, and its inverse has the same property.

I cannot see why $L$ is invertible. Surjectivity I understand it as $L$ maps open balls of radius $r$ to open balls of the same radius, then take $r \to \infty$. For injectivity I have zero idea. It could be related to $L(B) = B$ having the range as its domain, but I could not make any progress from this.

Please share any thoughts on it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: My understanding is that in Problem 1, you are asking why $L$ maps $B$ onto $B$? Here $B$ is the unit open ball centered at the origin, and if linear operator means what I think it means, it sends the origin to the origin. Also, fifth edition exists?

Comment: The problem is I cannot prove that the center of $L(B)$ is $0$. It is true that $0$ must be in all the image balls, but this only imply the center of the image ball is in the unit ball as I demonstrated. Also, the 5th ed exists but it is not that "accessible" on the internet. I bought it from Pearson.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The missing ingredient in your first question is the symmetry of the unit ball. For a set $S\subset\mathbb{R}^n$, let $-S = \{-s:s\in S\}$. It is easy to check that for the unit ball $B$, we have $-B = B$. Thus $L(B)=L(-B)$. On the other hand, if $L(B) = y_0+B$, then $L(-B) = -y_0+B$. For these two sets to coincide we must have $y_0=-y_0$, i.e., when $y_0=0$.

For the invertibility claim, there are a couple of options. One is to note that a linear map fails to be injective precisely when it has a kernel. If $L$ has nontrivial kernel, then $L(B)$ would lie in a proper subspace of dimension at most $n-1$ by the rank-nullity theorem, so $L(B)$ could not be the entire unit ball.

Comment: Very clear. I think I understand it now. Much appreciated.